# Command is not responding

Tags: command-line, ssh, execute-command, github

I am trying to add ssh key to Gerrit account.
$ssh -p PortNumber username@xyz.com

After hitting enter, it becomes just standstill. Not seeing any progress, and even the command is not coming out after I waited for more time.

Even `ping google.com` command is exhibiting same behaviour.

How do I know what is happening behind, whether it is waiting for internet or waiting for user input, something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: add `-vvv` as option to `ssh` to get verbose output.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].